# How to insert people picker data into share point list

Tags: 2013, people-picker

I have created a  custom people picker using jquery in sand box solutions,upto here working fine.
My question is how to insert custom people picker data into sharepoint list people and group column
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom people picker on your form, then follow below steps to achieve what you are looking for:

Keep sharepoint people control hidden on form using `Style="display:none"`inline property.

Using jquery Once you get the value of user into your custom control, copy it and assign to the default sharepoint control:
Ex

```
var inputUserField = $("div[title='People Picker']"); // This will target to the input box of sharepoint people control.

inputUserField.val(customUserControl.val()); // customUserControl is the custom control you have created.
```

Thanks